# Difference global maven settings.xml and maven settings.xml in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

We are adding some settings.xml files in Jenkins as managed script.

What is the difference between global maven settings.xml and maven settings.xml in Jenkins? I don't know what type I have to choose in which case

Comment: you should really mark cheffe's answer as correct. Unless you have more questions, but this is fairly old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the user documentation on the settings dialogue of Jenkins:

> The settings element in the settings.xml file contains elements used
>   to define values which configure Maven execution in various ways, like
>   the pom.xml, but should not be bundled to any specific project, or
>   distributed to an audience. These include values such as the local
>   repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and
>   authentication information. There are two locations where a
>   settings.xml file per default may live:
>
> ```
> The Maven install - default: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> A user's install - default: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
> ```
>
> The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter
>   settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists,
>   their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being
>   dominant.

So the **global maven settings.xml** is the one that would be of the Maven install and the **maven settings.xml** would be the one that is of the user's install.